# OpenWrite Error: "already open as"

Tags: files-and-directories

Mathematica gives the error "[file] already open as [file]" when I execute OpenWrite, even if I use a completely new name and pointer.  Could this be related to using both Write and WriteString within the program?

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica StackExchange! Can you please edit the question and include your piece of code so that we can try ti reproduce your problem?

Comment: Close and restart the kernel and check if you still get the same message.